# Displaying nested objects from JSON response

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs

This may be a simple fix but I'm new to react so I appologize in advance. I have nested data that I would like to display on a list. The data is being pulled and displayed below.

```
data: [
{
  "id": 1,
  "domain_url": "localhost",
  "created_on": "2020-05-26",
  "config": [
    {
      "test_name": "test",
      "test_description": "test",
    }
  ]
}
]
```

I can get the **domain_url** and **created_on** displaying just fine but nothing I've tried gets any of the config items to appear.

below is the current method I'm using.

```
<tbody>
  {this.props.data.map((data) => (
  <tr key={data.id}>
    <td>{data.domain_url}</td>
    <td>
      {data.config.map((sub) => {
        sub.test_name;
      })}
    </td>
    <td>{data.created_on}</td>
    <td>
    ...
```

how can I get the test name from the config array to display? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Your `data.config.map()` is not returning anything. Change the line to `return sub.test_name;`

Comment: thank you, I was unaware that I needed to return it very new to this. This solved it.

Comment: You can alternately eliminate the surrounding `{}`, like this: `data.config.map((sub) => sub.test_name)`. That does an implicit return of `sub.test_name`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks right - I think you just need to add a ‘return’ in front of your ‘sub.test_name;’